# Running Get-MessageTrackingLog as a job in Powershell

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I'm trying to create an Exchange 2010 script that will search each transport server as a job. I try the following:

```
$transportserver = get-transportserver
foreach ($ts in $transportserver)
{
     $ts_name = $ts.name

     $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ts_name
     Invoke-Command -Session $s -Script { Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010; Get-MessageTrackingLog -server $args[0] } -Args $ts_name
}
```

But I get the error:

> ```
> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: serverSettings
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-MessageTrackingLog], ArgumentNullException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
>      System.ArgumentNullException,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.TransportLogSearchTasks.GetMessageTrackingLog
> ```

I've tried a few variations like adding more parameters but it returns the same error.

Comment: Just to rule it out, is it possible that you're not running this against a Hub or Edge server?

Comment: I'm both running it on and against Hub Transport servers.

Answer (score 0):

The script looks very simple, so i feel like your problem lays elsewhere.
maybe try

```
invoke-command -computername $srv {Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010; Get-MessageTrackingLog}
```

If that fails maybe walk towards another solution, with psExec fx.
This is just a quick copy/paste from my personal scripts.

```
$ps = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process
$ps.StartInfo.Filename = "O:\pstools\psexec.exe"

Foreach ($strComputer in $Servers)
{   
    $ps.StartInfo.Arguments = " \\" 
    $ps.StartInfo.Arguments += $strComputer.Name 
    $ps.StartInfo.Arguments += " gpupdate.exe /target:computer /force"
    $ps.start()
    $ps.WaitForExit()
}
```

Comment: You have to pass a parameter with the get-MessageTrackingLog so your first example returns an error. I can't use other executables so unfortunately the second example is not an option.